# Negative margin is working on box, but not on contents inside of it

Tags: html, css

(Please note current answers provided are unclear)

I've got a web-site header that is in two parts: left and right, with the left 130px high, and the right side 185px high. I laid these out using float.

I've got content underneath the left header side in a div that I want to move up so it is immediately below the left header.   When I give this div a border and specify a negative margin, the border moves up as expected.  However, the content inside the div is not moving up.  It hangs down below the 185px (apparently from the right header).  Note I have the padding set to zero on this div.  What am I doing wrong?

It doesn't work in recent versions of Chrome or Firefox.  Thanks.

Relevant HTML code is:

```
<body style="margin: 0px">
    <div class="page">
        <div>
            <div class="leftHeader">
                <div class="headerMissingEnd">
                    <!-- img src="images/header.png" Title" width="750px" / -->
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="rightHeader">
                <div style="height:185px;padding:0px">
                    <canvas margin:"0" width="360px" height="185px" loop="true" fps="30" bgcolor="#ffffff" init="fn_canvas">
                    </canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
        </div>
       <div style="margin-top:-60px; padding:0;border: 1px dashed red">
          some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected
       </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.clear {
   clear: both;
   line-height: 0px;
}

.page {
   width: 1005px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   color: #333;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.leftHeader {
    float: left;
    width: 630px; 
    margin: 0px auto;   
 }

.rightHeader {
    float: left;
    width: 360px; 
    height: 185px;
    margin: 0px auto;   
 }

.headerMissingEnd {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 130px;
   background: url('images/header-left.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I'd think that an SO user with more than 1k rep would know to post some code. ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest you to try increasing right header's height and see, if div's contents' position is dependent on right header's height.

Comment: @Gman - if I increase the height of the right side to 200px from 185px then both the border and the content inside of the div (just some text), drop down 15px.

Comment: Ok @isherwood I will post some simplified code

Comment: Works ok http://jsfiddle.net/BMpqP/3/

Comment: @Gman please see I added the relevant problem code, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use negative `margin` to change element's relative position. Use `position: relative; top: -60px;` instead:

```
<div style="position: relative; top: -60px; padding:0;border: 1px dashed red;">
      some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected
</div>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/BMpqP/10/) Then you can fix wrapping issues with the `width: 600px;`.

---

**Old answer text**:
So, that's because your last `div` is 100% in width and is not `float`ed. (The default behavior for `div`.)

When the div is not floated, the text in it interacts with the floating divs even outside it. If you add more text, you'll see (http://jsfiddle.net/BMpqP/6/) that it's for the text not to clash with the other header that is higher.

My proposed solution is to float the div and set the size to it:

```
<div style="margin-top:-60px; padding:0;border: 1px dashed red; float: left; width: 630px;">
    some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected
</div>
```

Then the text will be okay, and the main content of the page would also be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BMpqP/7/

Comment: Thanks.  If I just specify a width, say of 300px, how come that isn't enough?

Comment: Also, if I want this div to be below the other 2, i.e. in stacked kind of fashion, isn't the general approach not to float it?

Comment: `If I just specify a width, say of 300px, how come that isn't enough`
It's somewhat complicated: the text (`inline`) part is nested in the div (`block`), so the text boundary is set to the lowest point of the upper row (which is the row of floated divs).

Comment: So I have to float this div too is what you are saying?

Comment: What do you think of relative/offset positioning for stuff like this?

Comment: @Ray See my updated answer, it's not the `float` that is the problem, but rather the negative `margin`. When you use negative margin, apparently the text bounds are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want real smooth stacking without any hardcoded offsets, what you should really do is use `float: right;` for the headers. (The header parts will have to be switched places in the markup.)

```
    <div class="leftHeader">
        <div class="headerMissingEnd">
            <!-- img src="images/header.png" Title" width="750px" / -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="padding:0;border: 1px dashed red;">
        some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected some text that appears too low, not a top of div as expected
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

.clear {
       clear: both;
       line-height: 0px;
    }

```
.page {
   width: 1005px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   color: #333;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.leftHeader {
    float: right;
    width: 630px; 
    margin: 0px auto;   

    background-color: black;

    opacity: 0.5;
 }

.rightHeader {
    float: right;
    width: 375px; 
    height: 185px;
    margin: 0px auto; 

    opacity: 0.5;

    background-color: navy;
 }

.headerMissingEnd {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 130px;
   background: url('images/header-left.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this isn't obvious to me.  Why should the leftHeader get a float: right?